# Hotswap Spring Application with war deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, hotswap

I have an application built in Spring Tool Suite and using angular as well for frontend. I am building my maven and the deploying the war in Tomcat. While the Spring dev-tools work fine for any application when it is deployed form the tomcat container within STS but not when I put the war in external Tomcat. Is there any way to hotSwap the application other than blackboxing my javascript in Chrome. Can anyone list down the complete steps to follow. I'm a noob.

I have already put a dependency sping-devtools in maven. There are many answers related to that but none of them is working. It is a big project and takes 4 minutes to build and then I need to deploy it in tomcat which is a lot of burden.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking to hot reload the static files. In IntelliJ, it's simple as saving your code changes and doing a *Build Project* `CTRL + F9`. It's even better if you install a Live Reload extension for your browser so that any changes made is refreshed automatically. There are also other similar options for compile & build automatically in IntelliJ as well other IDEs such as Eclipse.

Comment: In IntelliJ it is working for me too. But I need to implement in Spring Tool Suite. That is the problem.